# Python - Reproducible random number using a row level seed

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to create a random number using a row level key as the seed. The logic being that if the dataset arrives in a different order the random number generated should still be the same because it has the same key.

I've built two solutions. One is fast but doesn't work. The second works, but is slow and won't scale. My intuition is that the first solution *should* work, but I'm having trouble working out how what I'm passing in interacts with the numpy.random.SeedSequence function. What am I missing here? What do I need to change to get the generate the same type of output as the second.

Thanks for your help :)

```
# Minimum reproducible example for the problem I'm trying to solve.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create test data set
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(0, 1000)})

#------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# This should work? It's nice and quick.                                 #
# 5.9 ms ± 84.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each) #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Create random generator and build base case
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=test_df.id.values)
test_df['random_one'] = rng.random(size = 1000)

# Reorder the data & regenerate the random number
test_df.sort_values('id', ascending=False, inplace=True)
rng_two = np.random.default_rng(seed=test_df.id.values)
test_df['random_two'] = rng_two.random(size = 1000)

print('First approach works?: ',np.sum(test_df['random_one'] == test_df['random_two']))
print(test_df.head())
print('\n')

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#
# This does work. It's pretty slow even for a 1k rows dataset           #
# 175 ms ± 1.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) #
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#
list_of_random_one = []
for row in range(len(test_df)):
    row_seed = int(test_df.iloc[row]['id'])
    np.random.seed(row_seed)
    list_of_random_one.append(np.random.uniform(size = 1)[0])

test_df['random_loop_one'] = list_of_random_one
test_df.sort_values('random_loop_one', inplace = True)

list_of_random_two = []
for row in range(len(test_df)):
    row_seed = int(test_df.iloc[row]['id'])
    np.random.seed(row_seed)
    list_of_random_two.append(np.random.uniform(size = 1)[0])

test_df['random_loop_two'] = list_of_random_two

print('Second approach works?:',np.sum(test_df['random_loop_one']) == np.sum(test_df['random_loop_two']))
print(test_df.head())
```

Comment: `random number generated should still be the same` how is it then random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following function :

```
def gen_random(df, seed_col, name):
    """
    df :       Name of the dataframe
    seed_col : string, name of the column considered as seed values
    name :     string, our new column of random numbers
    """
    np.random.seed(df[seed_col])
    df[name] = [np.random.uniform(size = 1)[0] for i in range(len(df))]
```

Output :

```
>>> gen_random(test_df, 'id', 'Example_1')
>>> gen_random(test_df, 'id', 'Example_2')
>>> test_df
...
    id  random_one  random_two  random_loop_one random_loop_two Example_1   Example_2
742 742 0.656092    0.502012    0.001283    0.001283    0.849736    0.849736
886 886 0.000823    0.956839    0.001409    0.001409    0.147026    0.147026
252 252 0.175442    0.783874    0.005413    0.005413    0.386525    0.386525
954 954 0.324023    0.720096    0.006020    0.006020    0.921842    0.921842
481 481 0.840997    0.748107    0.007554    0.007554    0.824039    0.824039
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
799 799 0.656579    0.442743    0.996610    0.996610    0.550010    0.550010
826 826 0.252229    0.728976    0.996932    0.996932    0.304821    0.304821
676 676 0.159381    0.755586    0.996980    0.996980    0.807912    0.807912
543 543 0.193006    0.469072    0.997275    0.997275    0.572492    0.572492
319 319 0.545615    0.958803    0.998445    0.998445    0.773263    0.773263
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. I don't think your function works as expected. If you sort the test_df data frame between the gen_random calls the random number will be inconsistent. 

Also I think there's a typo in the first line of your function, you've called the random seed on the *test_df* dataframe not df.

Comment: `test_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(0, 1000)})`

`gen_random(test_df, 'id', 'random_one')`

`test_df.sort_values('random_one', inplace = True)`

`gen_random(test_df, 'id', 'random_two')`

`assert np.sum(test_df['random_one'] == test_df['random_two']) == len(test_df), 'Random Numbers not consistent'`

Comment: With the adjustment you've made the code now works :) And it runs pretty fast! Thanks for your help.